# Where is DataFrame.index documented?

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I looked up the pandas documentation but couldn't find it here ?

I am looking for the listing of this dataframe attribute in the documentation

```
df.index
```

http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.20/api.html?highlight=dataframe

Answer (score 0):

For the corresponding version of pandas, here's the [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Index.html)

Comment: Not quite. Why is the attribute `index` not listed for DataFrame object in documentation for DataFrame ? Or where is it listed?

Answer (score 0):

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html?highlight=index#index-objects

That looks to be it; was there a specific attribute you were looking for?